# reformating an RSS feed with jQuery

Tags: jquery, rss, reformat

I am currently pulling an RSS feed in which the the format is essentially title->image->text content.  I would like to reformat it so that the image comes first.  I am currently trying:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("li.rssitem").each(function() {
$(".rssdescription a img").remove().insertBefore("h3");
    });
    });
</script>
```

HTML looks like:

```
<ul id="rssitems">

<li class="rssitem"><h3 class="rsstitle"></h3>
<div class="rssdescription"><p><a href="#"><img src="..."></a></p><p>content</p></div></li>

<li class="rssitem"><h3 class="rsstitle">><a href="#">...</a></h3>
<div class="rssdescription"><p><a href="#"><img src="..."></a></p><p>content</p></div></li>

</ul>
```

Which works except that there are many items (all with images) in the list.  This code puts ALL the images before all the h3's.  I am clearly having trouble looping correctly.  Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
$("li.rssitem").each(function() {
    var target = $(this).children("h3");
    $(this).find("img").each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $(target).before($(this));
    });    
});
```

I didn't tested it, so I'm not sure it will work out of the box, but hopefully you'll be able to modify it to suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the try, but alas, it does not seem to be doing anything. I also thought that this should have done the trick: `$("li.rssitem").each(function() {
    var target = $(this).filter("h3");
    $(".rssdescription a img").each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $(target).insertBefore(this);
    });
});`  changed the .before to .insertBefore and closed the parenthesis after img. no go just yet

Comment: I got it ;) I edited my answer with the working code ! filter() wasn't the good method to call, to search in the children of an element, we must use find()

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the selector that is inside of the loop. It's finding all of the img tags, and not just the one inside of the desired li.rssitem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("li.rssitem").each(function() {
            $(this).find(".rssdescription a img").insertBefore("h3");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Let me know if this solves the issue that you're having.

**UPDATE:** Got rid of the remove() as it's gonna screw with ya. Thanks DT.

Comment: I don't think you need the `remove()` step, [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) will move the element to the new position (and not clone it), according to the [api link](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).

Comment: glad to be of help :) (also, if you respond to someone it's best to preface their name with the `@` symbol, that way it notifies the person you're responding to...) +1 =)

Comment: Thanks @David Thomas! I've been using Stack Overflow for a while now as a learning resource and am now just beginning to help others out. As a general rule, when I search Tech questions on Google I throw in a "+stack" to make sure I fidn the right question / answer. :)

Comment: 't is a good method! And remember, asking questions is as helpful as providing answers... =)